# Fan always on HP Pavilion dv6-6195sp

Tags: 12.04, fan, hp-pavilion

After install Ubuntu 12.04 (fresh install) on my HP Pavilion dv6-6195sp the processor fan it´s always on...

Can someone help ?

Comment: Hello João and bem-vindo em AskUbuntu. Could you please edit your question to tell whether your install is an upgrade (from Ubuntu 11.10 for example) or a "fresh" install?

Answer (score 1):

Try [installing the proprietary drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-a-graphics-or-wireless-card-driver) if you haven't done it yet. Then, try installing [Psensor](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/psensor), which is a hardware sensor including temperatures and fan speed.

Don't hesitate to update your question with the results you get.

Comment: Is the rationale behind this that the proprietary nvidia driver is known to do better power management than the open source one?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my pavillion dv6 after fresh intallation of ubuntu 12.04.
The fan was 100% ON like if the computer is doing MAX performance  but I was still running nothing.
I realize it was "compiz"  using most of the CPU . 
After some time looking for post I follow the next steps:

open conpiz config setting mannager ( in terminal type "ccsm") then go to opengl (under general) and uncheck te option "sync to vblank"

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

What helped me on my notebook (an old IBM though but should work on most devices) was to install the cpufrequtils. cpufreq will decrease the cpu frequency when the power is not needed and so the CPU will not be that hot which results in lower fan speeds.

cpufreq-info will give you an output like that:

```
user@host:~$ cpufreq-info 
cpufrequtils 002: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2006
Report errors and bugs to linux@brodo.de, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: centrino
  CPUs which need to switch frequency at the same time: 0
  hardware limits: 798 MHz - 2.00 GHz
  available frequency steps: 798 MHz, 1.06 GHz, 1.33 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 2.00 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: userspace, ondemand, conservative, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 798 MHz and 2.00 GHz.
                  The governor "conservative" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 798 MHz.
```

Comment: `cpufreq-info` just informs you what cpufreq policy you are currently using, what capabilities your hardware and so on. The actual cpufreq managing code is part of your kernel. The cpufreq subsystem in the kernel should work out of the box.